# Using enum class values in constexpr branches

Tags: c++, enums, c++17, constexpr, tag-dispatching

the code below prints `val2` on both `f()` calls. What would be a proper way to execute specific branch in `f()` based on enum value ?

```
enum class E
{
    val1,
    val2
};

using val1_t = std::integral_constant<E, E::val1>;
using val2_t = std::integral_constant<E, E::val2>;
    

template <typename T>
void f(T t)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, val1_t>)
    {
        std::cerr << "val1\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "val2\n";
    }
}


int main()
{
    f(E::val1);
    f(E::val2);
}
```

Comment: `std::is_same_v` is comparing types, not values. `E::val1` and `E::val2` have the same type (`E`), which isn't the same type as `std::integral_constant<...>`

Comment: `f(val1_t{})` would work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you move the enum into the template parameter, then you could use

```
template <E val>
void f()
{
    if constexpr (val == E::val1)
    {
        std::cerr << "val1\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "val2\n";
    }
}
```

And you would use it like

```
int main()
{
    f<E::val1>();
    f<E::val2>();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. So there is no way to somehow infer std::integral_constant-generated-type from passed enum value ? Maybe not with std::is_same_v, but somehow else ?
I would still like to have something like `f(E::val1)` at call site.

Comment: @psb You could do something like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/283b6d2daa3a3d6f)

Comment: @psb The issue with function parameters is they are never compile time constants.  That means you can't use them where a compile time constant is required.

Comment: @psb That first example was a little to complicated.  Here is a reduced version: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c6ba1f71a2d9f76f

Comment: Yeah, I more or less understand that, but I've been thinking that since all enum values are known at compile time, there may be a way to deduce a type, based on enum value, from enum value at compile time.

Comment: So, I guess, I can substitute `enum` with something like this:
`struct E
{
 static inline struct Val1{} val1;
 static inline struct Val2{} val2;
};`

Comment: @psb You could do that.  That technique is called tag dispatch.  Basically, you use the types of the parameter instead of it's value to do something.